# Core Data: In which case would a NSManagedObject never obtain a permanent ID

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject

Using core data, I am passing objectIDs between various methods to perform various operation.
I seem to have an error because of an object ID being temporary, even when forcing it to become permanent.

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context=[(id)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] theContext];
__block MyObject *myObject;
[context performBlockAndWait:^(void){
    myObject= [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"MyObject" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    myObject.name=@"thename";
    [(id)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] saveTheContext];
}];
NSLog(@"is temporary before calling obtainpermanentid=%d",[myObject.objectID isTemporaryID]);
BOOL b=[context obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObject:myObject] error:nil];
NSLog(@"is temporary after calling obtainpermanentid=%d",[myObject.objectID isTemporaryID]);
```

In this case, I would expect to obtain a permanent objectID after the save.
It's not happening
I am trying to force this by calling obtainPermanentIDsForObjects (which returns true), yet the object still has a temporary ID after that.

Any ideas on what condition could cause an object ID to stay temporary?

Comment: Where is `myObject` declared? I see a declaration inside the block, but you're also using it outside the block.

Comment: You should also check the return value of `obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:` and use the `error:` parameter.

Comment: @TomHarrington my apologies, I had reformatted the code for the question and forgot a couple of edits, I edited my post with the declaration of myObject

Comment: @MartinR I do that in the debugger, the return value of obtainPermanentIDsForObjects is true

Comment: I can't be certain but I'm a little concerned about calling `obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:` outside of a `performBlock`. That should really be synchronized using a block call. Why that would lead to your results I'm not sure, but I recommend fixing that.

Comment: @TomHarrington it should not matter as the block is 'performandwait', but I did test inside the block and things are the same

Comment: I usually call `obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:` _before_ the save.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, this code was added on top of an existing implementation that is using NSIncrementalStore (through AFIncrementalStore).

As part of subclassing NSIncrementalStore, the method `obtainPermanentIDsForObjects` is overridden, and in this case that method is returning the temporary object ID under certain conditions.